# How to change php CLI configuration in laradock?

Tags: php, docker, laradock

Im using latest laradock with basic configuration.

I created my.ini file with some settings and edit php-fpm/Dockerfile as follow:

```
COPY ./my.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
```

When i run `phpinfo()` in browser I see the following:

[image: phpinfo()]

So, `my.ini` file successfully loaded. But when I run `php -i` in workspace bash:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/8.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ast.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-msgpack.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-redis.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini,
/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

**How can I add my ini file when I running CLI commands?**

Comment: See this? `/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d` and you copied your `my.ini` to `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d`. I would also copy it to `/etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d` in your Dockerfile. The cli has its own separate php.ini